# Improving text readability with CSS

Tags: html, css, user-experience, usability

I am trying to style [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjxZRj) and I can't quite get the right CSS for the text to make it more readable and not looking overcrowded.

Core CSS:

```
p{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I plan to use the improved CSS both for the normal, desktop version and for mobile. Here's a screen of what I think is a great example of readability for mobile.

[image: BBC mobile version]

Comment: Have you messed around with the antialiasing settings? Is it a line spacing issue or...

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, but, FWIW, `line-height` value should be unitless for the value to inherit correctly to child elements, i.e. it should be just `line-height: 1.25`, without `em`. Also, `text-align: justify` is typically considered bad practice since it leads to big spaces between long words. By the way, it's generally better to set things like `line-height` for the root element (`HTML`), and then override it for specific containers if needed.

Comment: @Phix, I've messed around with     -font-smoothing and     text-rendering. But I think     line-height is also part of the issue.

Comment: @MaratTanalin, ok, line-height, text-align. But how about font-size? Are these the only 3 factors that can be tinkered?

Comment: You should probably read something about typography in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`line-height`, `font-size`, `color` are all good. I usually use `color: #333` or `color: #777` to create less contrast between a white background and black letters.

You may also want to consider [`letter-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing), which creates a more "airy" sense with more whitespace between text characters:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    letter-spacing: .05em
}

p {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility !important;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
}
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojaMEy

Comment: I've tweaked it a little bit, the letter-spacing and color greatly helped. Plus, a thumbs-up from co-developers.

Comment: You could add a width to the p element, as each line of text should contains 45 to 75 chars (35 to 50 on mobile devices): `width: 30em;` would fit this. You should also add a margin, so the text has no distractors - but this is rarely possible.

Answer (score 0):

With a font-size of 24px and a line-height set at 1.5em the text will look much like the example you have provided. After that just break up the paragraphs into easily readable chunks.
That seems to be the simplest answer as long as I'm not misunderstanding the problem.